# AdMob mediation Manifest error with InMobi ads

Tags: android, admob, inmobi, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying to implement AdMob mediation with InMobi, but the ads won't show. I am following [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/inmobi) and I have added both SDK and AndroidX:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:7.3.0.0'

android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

However, when I use the [Mediation Test Suite](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation-test-suite) I get a Manifest error as on the image:

[image]

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution over at IronSource mediation center. All I had to do is add this to manifest:

```
        <activity
                android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <receiver
                android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

P.S. **ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver** is deprecated but needed.